# Does rain count as me watering, or a visitor watering?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

In Animal Crossing New Horizons, I understand that rain waters all flowers on the island. However, there’s a mechanic where folks visiting your island who water your flowers can have the waterings stack to be more effective than just me watering alone.

My question is does rain count as me watering the flowers, or a visitor watering? Do I get more of an effect by watering while it’s raining?

Answer (score 2):

Rain will be treated like all flowers **were** watered, but it doesn't count as the player watering.

Also, it wouldn't count in Nook Miles+ challenges.

Comment: What is “ware watering” supposed to mean?  Should that be “were watered”?

Comment: @jwodder I think they were trying to say rain treats it as if all flowers were watered, but it doesn't count for player watering.